# String manipulation in Java (ensure string always with exactly “//“ in front)

Tags: java, string

What is the best way to ensure the following:

I want to make sure that a certain string will always be preceded by `“//“`. i.e. exactly two forward slashses.

Guidelines, on the input string:

- It may contain other slashes within the string; (e.g. `photos/comments`);
- It may already contain 0-n number of other slashes in the beginning (e.g. `///photos`, `/photos`, `photos`, `//photos`, etc.).

**EDIT**

Btw: if the String is not correctly formatted, I would like to fix-it so that it does.

Comment: What do you want it to do with the "///photos" example?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, is this to prevent directory/path traversal attacks?  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal  If  so, OWASP has a guide to preventing such an attack...

Comment: you can concat `//` like this `"//"+myString`

Comment: @JonSkeet In this case, it should always just be “//photos”, i.e. fix it so that it is always double-slash, regardless what input.

Comment: @DavidStratton No it is for xpath purposes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the regex `"^/*"` with `"//"`:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^/*", "//");
```

This will remove all leading forward slashes (if any) and insert exactly two slashes at the beginning of the string. It will not touch any existing slashes that are not at the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

See the [String#matches(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method:

Usage for exactly two slashes on the front:

```
boolean result = "//".matches("^/{2}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourString="something";
yourString = !yourString.startsWith("//")?"//"+yourString:"";
```

Answer (score 0):

string = "//" + string.replaceFirst("^/*", "");

Answer (score 0):

No slow regexps + minimal memory/recreation overhead.

```
public String fix(String str) {
    int n = 0;
    while(n < str.length() && str.charAt(n) == '/') { ++n; }

    switch (n) {
        case 0: return "//" + str;
        case 1: return "/" + str;
        case 2: return str;
        default: return str.substring(n - 2); 
    }
}
```